# NameError in CompetitorsController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting this problem when I run this code in server. In my **localhost** everything is running fine. But when I **deploy** my code in the **server** it shows me the error. 
**I am using FERRET SERARCH IN MODEL.**

**NameError in CompetitorsController#index**

**uninitialized constant CompetitorsController::Competitor**

/opt/ruby_enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:102:in `const_missing'

/home/troche/mrecip_tool/releases/20091219131859/app/controllerscompetitors_controller .rb :19:in `index'

**My controller is**

class CompetitorsController < ApplicationController

include AuthenticatedSystem
  layout 'application'

auto_complete_for :proscribed, :competitor
  auto_complete_for :fee_earner, :fee_earner

protect_from_forgery :only => [:tag]

before_filter :login_required, :only => [:index, :show, :new, :edit]

@@total_company = 70

def index
    @compet = Competitor.find(:all)   **### GETTING ERROR IN THIS LINE**

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @compet }
end
```

end

def show
    @competitor = Competitor.find(params[:id])

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @competitor }
end
```

end

end

---

**My Model is**

class Competitor < ActiveRecord::Base

validates_presence_of :fee_earner_id, :notes

belongs_to :fee_earner
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :user

acts_as_ferret :fields =>[:competitor, :client, :subject_matter],:remote => true

end

Comment: First things first, format your code correctly.  It's impossible to read it like this.  The little question mark by the editing box should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Change `Competitor` to `::Competitor` in the erroring line to explicitly say what scope you want.