# Rails - Child model is not found in an administrate controller, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If have a model `Donut` which is a child of an abstract model `Food`:
( This also applies to every other childs of `Food` )

```rb
# models/food.rb
class Food < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
  ...
end
```

```rb
# models/food/donut.rb
class Food::Donut < Food
  ...
end
```

In all of my application using `Food::Donut` works fine, except in an administrate controller:

```rb
# controllers/manage/application_controller.rb
module Manage
  class ApplicationController < Administrate::ApplicationController
    ...
  end
end
```

```rb
# controllers/manage/tree_controller.rb
module Manage
  class TreesController < Manage::ApplicationController
    def some_method
      Tree.cut # This works as intended
      Food::Donut.eat # This fails with NameError: uninitialized constant Manage::Food::Donut
    end
  end
end
```

In a console I managed to "get it working" by defining FoodDonut:

```rb
FoodDonut = Food::Donut
module Manage
    class FakeController
        def fake_method
            puts FoodDonut.eat # Works
            puts Food::Donut.eat # fails
        end
    end
end
```

But doing that in my code seems to break every other controller.

And I don't get why is works for `Tree` but not for `Food::Donut` specificaly ?

I'm fairly new to ruby, appologies if anything is unclear.

Comment: Do you have a class `Manage::Food`? If that exists, Ruby looks up starting from `Manage::FakeController` and asks "is there are `Manage::FakeController::Food`? No. Is there a `Manage::Food`? Yes. OK, there must be a `Manage::Food::Donut` then... no! Well, that's an error then".

Comment: No I don't have anything besides the controller in the manage class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways around this.

The first is to define the subclasses in the same file as the parent class:

```rb
class Food < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  class Donut < Food
    # ...
  end
end
```

The second (which I recommend) is to avoid having `Food` as the parent class, and instead having something else, like `Food::Base`:

```rb
# food.rb
module Food
  # ...
end

# food/base.rb
module Food
  class Base < ApplicationRecord
  end
end

# food/donut.rb
module Food
  class Donut < Food::Base
    # ...
  end
end
```

Now, as to why this happens, it's a bit of Ruby, and a bit of Rails's autoloader. It's definitely not Administrate's fault :-) so I recommend that you remove that `administrate` tag. The problem is with this definition:

```rb
# models/food/donut.rb
class Food::Donut < Food
  ...
end
```

When Ruby reads this file, `Food` may or may not have been defined yet. It's in another file that may not have loaded yet unless you have explicitly `require`d it. The bottom line is that Ruby can't define `Donut` in the namespace `Food` because it doesn't know what `Food` is.

Rails could try to autoload it, but for some reason it doesn't. I don't know the details of the autoload well enough to tell you why. I can't reproduce this issue now with Rails 6.1, and it may depend on your version of Rails.

Also, Ruby can't assume that `Food` is a class and create it on the spot, for two reasons: 1) it could be a module instead of a class, 2) it could inherit from something and we don't know what this something is. (In fact it does inherit from `ApplicationRecord` in your example).

When defining nested classes and modules, always follow this guide:

```rb
#
# bad
#

# the_namespace.rb
module TheNamespace # could be a class
  # ...
end

# the_namespace/the_class.rb
class TheNamespace::TheClass
  # ...
end

#
# good
#

# the_namespace.rb
module TheNamespace # could be a class
  # ...
end

# the_namespace/the_class.rb
module TheNamespace # could be a class
  class TheClass
    # ...
  end
end
```

However your case is a bit more complicated because the namespace class also inherits from something else (from `ApplicationRecord`). Therefore it's simpler to just have a different class `Base` that acts as the parent for all food classes, as I propose at the start.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I had to add `::` in front of `Food::Donut`:

```rb
# controllers/manage/tree_controller.rb
module Manage
  class TreesController < Manage::ApplicationController
    def some_method
      Tree.cut # This works as intended
      ::Food::Donut.eat
    end
  end
end
```

This was the answer that got me there :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2842864/4047185

I still don't understand why it's not needed for the `Tree` model.